# How to read local csv files in JupyterLab?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I wrote this simple pandas code as below in JupyterLab to read test.csv which is a local file in my desktop:

[JupyterLab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlXOW.png)

but when i run the code it gets error as :

[FileNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSq25.png)

Is there any way to read a local csv file by using JupyterLab (https://jupyter.org/try) web version?

Edit: Update code as:

[Updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKBsH.png)

Edit2: 
[Location is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07rZL.png)

Answer (score 3):

@MCoder This is what I tried to do.

Uploaded the local csv file into JupyterLab and then read it, otherwise it was throwing the same **FileNotFound** error.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: yes, i had implemented the same and it works as you explained. What i need is read csv without uploading there, but reading it from local computer.

Comment: It is a web version. It won't be able to locate file in your local system. I tried that even, but didn't work.

Comment: @MCoder ICYMI JupyterLab has drag-n-drop so that you can drag your local file into the file browser panel of JupyterLab to transfer file to remote system running Jupyter. You’d need to have a JupyterLab installed locally to read local file without transfer to remote system.